# How to match line size with regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following code, trying to match pyramids of increasing `*` count, surrounded by an equivalent number of spaces on either side.

```
//pyramid
var p = "     *     \n" +
        "    ***    \n" +
        "   *****   \n" +
        "  *******  \n" +
        " ********* \n" +
        "***********\n";
//not a pyramid - rows 2 and 3 do not increase in width
var np = "     *     \n" +
         "   *****   \n" +
         "   *****   \n" +
         "  *******  \n" +
         " ********* \n" +
         "***********\n";
//pyramid with more width variation, non-point top
var pspace = "          **          \n" +
             "         ****         \n" +
             "      **********      \n" +
             "    **************    \n" +
             "   ****************   \n" +
             "**********************\n";
final var REGEX = "((?<S>\\s*)(?<star>\\**)\\k<S>\\R(?=$|((?<S2>\\s*)(?<extra>\\*+)\\k<star>\\k<extra>\\k<S2>\\R)))+";
System.out.println("p is a pyramid: "+Pattern.matches(REGEX, p));
System.out.println("np is a pyramid: "+Pattern.matches(REGEX, np));
System.out.println("pspace is a pyramid: "+Pattern.matches(REGEX, pspace));
```

**Output:**

> p is a pyramid: true
>   np is a pyramid: false
>   pspace is a pyramid: true

The final thing I want to do is make sure that all "lines" of the input string are of equal length. At this point, I got completely stuck, as I couldn't really find anything but fixed-length String bounds (i.e. `X{min, max}`). So, here's what I'm wondering:

1. How can I make sure that all the lines within my string are pyramids (increasing number of stars from first line to last line (done), separated by new lines (done), centered within the spaces (done), and equal length lines (???))?
2. How can I simplify my regex to reduce the overuse of named capturing groups?

Comment: Honestly it might just be easier to determine the proposed height and width of the incoming period, then generate what the correct period should be in your code, and compare that string against the input.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I know it would probably be easier to compute this without regex. I was wondering whether Java regex has the power to do this at all, or whether I should just give up trying to find a way.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are incapable of doing the type of counting you are trying to accomplish, so you have to use a mixed strategy. Break up the string on newline boundaries then use a regular expression to match the leading and trailing spaces and the asterisks between them. But you will then have to see if the lengths of these matches meet your requirements by seeing how long these strings are using the `length` method that `String` objects possess:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String p = "     *     \n" +
                   "    ***    \n" +
                   "   *****   \n" +
                   "  *******  \n" +
                   " ********* \n" +
                   "***********\n";
        String[] lines = p.split("\n");
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\s*)(\\*+)(\\s*)$");
        int lastLength = 0;
        boolean isPyramid = true;
        for (String line : lines) {
            Matcher m = pattern.matcher(line);
            m.find();
            String spaces1 = m.group(1);
            String spaces2 = m.group(3);
            String asterisks = m.group(2);
            int len = asterisks.length();
            if (len <= lastLength || spaces1.length() != spaces2.length()) {
                isPyramid = false;
                break;
            }
            else {
                lastLength = len;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("p is a pyramid: " + isPyramid);    
    }
}
```